# SO Query with tag and wildcard term

Tags: support, search, tag-search

I want to search for questions that have the tag [ios] and one of the terms "decrypt" or "encrypt".

I have read the Help Center "How do I search?" but can't seem to come up with a search.

The obvious seems to be: [ios] *crypt
But this does not actually work.

As an example the question: [How would I encrypt a string on IOS and decrypt in windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25626760/)

Has the title: How would I encrypt a string on IOS and decrypt in windows?

This search finds it: [ios] decrypt
This search does not find it: [ios] *crypt

Is there something I am missing or perhaps not documented that will allow this search?

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a bug with a leading "*" on a search term under certain circumstances in that is it interpreted literally instead of as a meta-character. In particular it seems to be incorrect when a such a search term follows a tag.

Works: [ios] decrypt
Fails: [ios] *crypt
Works: *crypt [ios]

So the work-around is to put the search term prior to the tags.